# Have a Start Date and End Date, want to add all dates except Weekend Dates

Tags: sql-server-2016

So I have a Stored Procedure I am working on that has a User input a Start Date and End Date. I want to be able to insert all dates into a Table except for Weekend Dates. It will add the records to the table just fine, it just also adds the Weekend Dates. This is the closest I have gotten but it is not working as I expected. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

```
Declare @w_new_id int = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

          With theDates AS
         (SELECT @p_start_date as theDate
          UNION ALL  
          SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, theDate)
            FROM theDates
           WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, theDate) <= @p_end_date
         )



        INSERT INTO XLT_Vacation_Request_Dates
            (
                request_id,
                requester_id,
                requester_name,
                employee_id,
                employee_name,
                requested_date,
                status

            )
        SELECT
                @w_new_id,
                @p_requester_id,
                @w_user_name,
                @w_user,
                @p_employee_name,
                theDate,
                0 -- Unapproved
                from theDates where ((DATEPART(dw, @p_start_date) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1) OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your final select list to

```
SET DATEFIRST 7 -- ( Sunday )
SELECT *           
from theDates where DATEPART(WEEKDAY,theDates.theDate ) NOT IN(7,1)
```

Note 7,1 corresponds to Saturday and Sunday, change according to your region.

OR

```
SELECT *           
from theDates where DATENAME(DW, thedate) NOT IN('Saturday','Sunday')
```